# Написать программу, которая по заданному многочлену и значению x находила бы ответ

Tags: python-3.x

Многочлен
Васе задали несколько однотипных задач по математике: "Найти значение многочлена". Он хочет написать программу, которая по заданному многочлену и значению x находила бы ответ. Напишите такую программу!

Входные данные

В первой строке входного файла записан многочлен в виде суммы одночленов. Между одночленами находится знак + или –. Перед первым одночленом может быть знак –. Одночлен записывается как

[<Коэффициент>*]x[^<Степень>]

или

<Коэффициент>

где <Коэффициент> — натуральное число, не превосходящее 100, x — символ переменной (всегда маленькая латинская буква x), <Степень> — натуральное число, не превосходящее 4. Параметры, взятые в квадратные скобки, могут быть опущены. Во второй строке записано одно целое число — значение x.

Все числа в исходном файле по модулю не превосходят 100. Количество одночленов не более 10 (могут быть одночлены одинаковой степени).

Выходные данные

В выходной файл нужно записать одно число — значение данного многочлена при данном значении x.

Я попробовал разбивая на одночлены отдельно считаю но я не понимаю в чём проблемма при выделении чисел

````
def expression_result(expression):
    rez = 0
    for i in range(len(expression)):
        if expression[i] == "^":
            pl = expression.find("*")
            sum = int(expression[pl+1:i]) ** int(expression[i:-1])
            doPl = int(expression[:pl])
            rez = doPl * sum
            break
    return rez

    # example = "-2+x^1-3*x^2+x^2+100*x^3-2*x"
    expression = "-2+x^1-3*x^2+x^2+100*x^3-2*x"  # input()
    x = 0  # int(input())
    startIndex = 0

    rez = 0
    numsList = []
    symbolsList = []

    if expression[0] == "-":
        startIndex = 1

    while len(expression) > 0:
        for i in range(startIndex, len(expression)):
            if expression[i] in "-+":
                startIndex = i + 1
                numsList.append(expression_result(expression[:i-1]))
                symbolsList.append(expression[i])

    for i in range(len(numsList)):
        for j in range(len(symbolsList)):
            if j == 0 and symbolsList[j+1] == "+":
                rez += int(numsList[i]) + int(numsList[i+1])
            elif j == 0 and symbolsList[j+1] == "-":
                rez += int(numsList[i]) - int(numsList[i + 1])
            elif j == "+":
                rez += int(numsList[i+1]) + int(numsList[i+2])
            elif j == "-":
                rez += int(numsList[i + 1]) - int(numsList[i + 2])

    print(rez)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

А обязательно все руками писать?

**Может можно:**

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

expression = "-2+x^1-3*x^2+x^2+100*x^3-2*x"
x = 0
formula = expression.replace('x', str(x)).replace('^', '**')
print(parse_expr(formula))
```

На выходе:

```
−2
```

**Еще можно так сделать:**

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

expression = "-2+x^1-3*x^2+x^2+100*x^3-2*x"
x = symbols('x')
formula = parse_expr(expression.replace('^', '**'), local_dict={'x': x})
print('Формула:', formula)
for i in range(3):
    y = formula.subs(x, i)
    print(f'x={i}', f'y={y}')
```

Результат:

```
Формула: 100*x**3 - 2*x**2 - x - 2
x=0 y=-2
x=1 y=95
x=2 y=788
```

**Ну вот тогда интересненький, на мой взгляд, способ:**

```
from functools import reduce

expression = "-2+x^1-3*x^2+x^2+100*x^3-2*x"
x = 0
expression = 'x*x^3*3+3^3+1^5*4'
x = 2

class Pow:
    _symbol = '^'
    _action = '__pow__'

    def __init__(self, expr):
        self._expr = expr
        if self.__class__.__base__ is not object:
            self._parent = self.__class__.__base__
        else:
            self._parent = int

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self._symbol}, {self._expr})'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}({}, {} = {})'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            self._symbol,
            self._expr,
            str(self.__int__()))

    def __int__(self):
        split = self._expr.split(self._symbol)
        if len(split) > 1:
            return reduce(self._calc, [self._parent(i) for i in split])
        else:
            return int(self._parent(split[0]))

    def _calc(self, x, y):
        return getattr(int(x), self._action)(int(y))


class Mul(Pow):
    _symbol = '*'
    _action = '__mul__'


class Add(Mul):
    _symbol = '+'
    _action = '__add__'


print(Add(
    expression.replace('x', str(x))
))
```

Результат:

```
79
```

Класс для вычитания сам напишешь?

**А еще можно `int` перегрузить:** (обрати внимание на наличие минусов в `expression`, на перегрузку `__pow__`)

```
from functools import reduce
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.propagate = True

expression = "---2-x^1-3*x^2--x^2*2+100*x^3-2*x-3^x"
expression = '-2+x^1-3*x^2+x^2+100*x^3-2*x'
#expression = '-2+1^1-3^x'
x = -2

class Int(int):
    def __new__(cls, expr):
        """Для решения проблемы отрицательного x"""
        if isinstance(expr, str):
            expr = expr.replace('--', '+')
        return super().__new__(cls, expr)

    def __pow__(self, y):
        """Для решения проблемы: assert (-3).__pow__(2) == 9"""
        value = super().__pow__(y)
        if self < 0 and value > 0:
            value *= -1
        log.debug('%s(%s ^ %s = %s)', self.__class__.__name__, self, y, value)
        return value


class Pow(Int):
    _symbol = '^'

    def __new__(cls, expr):
        action = '__{}__'.format(cls.__name__.lower())
        parent = cls.__base__

        if expr == '':
            log.debug('%s(%s = %s)', cls.__name__, expr, 0)
            return super().__new__(cls, 0)

        split = expr.split(cls._symbol)
        if len(split) > 1:
            value = reduce(lambda x, y: getattr(x, action)(y),
                           [parent(i) for i in split])
            log.debug('%s_calc(%s = %s)', cls.__name__, expr, value)
        else:
            value = parent(split[0])
            log.debug('%s_get(%s = %s)', cls.__name__, expr, value)

        log.debug('%s(%s = %s)', cls.__name__, expr, value)
        return super().__new__(cls, value)


class Mul(Pow):
    _symbol = '*'


class Add(Mul):
    _symbol = '+'


class Calc(int):
    _x_sym = 'x'
    _parent = Add

    def __new__(cls, expr, x):
        while '--' in expr:
            expr = expr.replace('--', '+')
        expr = expr.replace('-', '+-')
        expr = expr.replace(cls._x_sym, str(x))
        value = cls._parent(expr)
        log.debug('%s(%s = %s)', cls.__name__, expr, value)
        return super().__new__(cls, value)

log.debug('(expr=%s) (x=%s)', expression, x)
print(Calc(expression, x))
```

Результат: `-792`

Вывод лога (для понимания хронологии событий):

```
DEBUG:__main__:(expr=---2-x^1-3*x^2--x^2*2+100*x^3-2*x-3^x) (x=2)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul( = 0)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul( = 0)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_get(-2 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(-2 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul_get(-2 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul(-2 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Int(-2 ^ 1 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_calc(-2^1 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(-2^1 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul_get(-2^1 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul(-2^1 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_get(-3 = -3)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(-3 = -3)
DEBUG:__main__:Int(2 ^ 2 = 4)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_calc(2^2 = 4)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(2^2 = 4)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul_calc(-3*2^2 = -12)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul(-3*2^2 = -12)
DEBUG:__main__:Int(2 ^ 2 = 4)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_calc(2^2 = 4)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(2^2 = 4)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_get(2 = 2)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(2 = 2)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul_calc(2^2*2 = 8)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul(2^2*2 = 8)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_get(100 = 100)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(100 = 100)
DEBUG:__main__:Int(2 ^ 3 = 8)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_calc(2^3 = 8)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(2^3 = 8)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul_calc(100*2^3 = 800)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul(100*2^3 = 800)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_get(-2 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(-2 = -2)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_get(2 = 2)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(2 = 2)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul_calc(-2*2 = -4)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul(-2*2 = -4)
DEBUG:__main__:Int(-3 ^ 2 = -9)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow_calc(-3^2 = -9)
DEBUG:__main__:Pow(-3^2 = -9)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul_get(-3^2 = -9)
DEBUG:__main__:Mul(-3^2 = -9)
DEBUG:__main__:Add_calc(++-2+-2^1+-3*2^2+2^2*2+100*2^3+-2*2+-3^2 = 779)
DEBUG:__main__:Add(++-2+-2^1+-3*2^2+2^2*2+100*2^3+-2*2+-3^2 = 779)
DEBUG:__main__:Calc(++-2+-2^1+-3*2^2+2^2*2+100*2^3+-2*2+-3^2 = 779)
```

Comment: Я попробовал этот вариант но на e-olymp нет этой беблиотеке поэто-му я вручную пишу

Comment: А `!pip install sympy` там не работает?

Answer (score 2):

```
def compute_monomial(monomial, x):
    if not monomial:
        return 0

    coeff = 1
    power = 1
    if 'x' in monomial:
        if monomial[0] == '-':
            coeff = -1
        if '*' in monomial:
            coeff = int(monomial.split('*')[0])
        if '^' in monomial:
            power = int(monomial.split('^')[-1])
        return coeff * x ** power
    else:
        coeff = int(monomial)
        return coeff


expression = '-2+x^1-3*x^2+x^2+100*x^3-2*x'
x = 0

result = 0
for monomial in expression.replace('-', '+-').split('+'):
    result += compute_monomial(monomial, x)

print(result)
# x = 0, result = -2
# x = 1, result = 95
# x = 2, result = 788
```

или

```
print(sum([compute_monomial(monomial, x) for monomial in expression.replace('-', '+-').split('+')]))
```

Comment: Не факт: `exp='-2+1^1-3^x*2'` `x=2` `=-19`. Впрочем, протестировав сейчас свой способ, я тоже обнаружил нечто новое: `x, y=-2, 2 ; x ** y == 4`. Т.ч. мы оба ошиблись.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov по условию либо `[<Коэффициент>*]x[^<Степень>]`, либо `[<Коэффициент>]`

Comment: Проблема возведения в четную степень остается: `expression = '1-x^2'
x = 2`, Проблема "-x": `expression = '1-x^3' x = -2`.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov повторюсь: `[<Коэффициент>*]x[^<Степень>]`, по условию скорее всего будет `1-1*x^2`

Comment: По условию, если я правильно понял квадратные скобки, четная степень, отсутствие множителя и отрицательный "х" - допустимы. Т.ч. оба примера из предыдущего комментария - допустимы.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov `-x` можно развернуть в `-1 * x`, про возможность ставить скобки в условии не сказано `(-x)`